# In git how do you point the MASTER pointer(branch) to another commit without merging?

Tags: git, version-control

I was working off of master and made some bad commits `C` & `D`.

```
A --- B --- C --- D (MASTER)
```

So I decided to restart the work from the known good commit `B` because I thought it would be easier than to try and find the mistake inside the `C` and/or `D` commits. But I also wanted the option of going back to `D` if the new attempt didn't work out for whatever reason. So I first created a detached HEAD pointing at `B` and then created a new branch (RETRY). My git repo now looks like this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D (MASTER)
       \
        \
         E --- F (RETRY)
```

As it turns out it was easier to just restart work at `B` and my commit `F` works wonderfully. So now my question is: how do I make MASTER point to F without merging with all the work done in `C` and `D` (but still keeping the `C` and `D` commits around in case I want to refer to them in the future)? I want to end up with:

```
A --- B --- C --- D
       \
        \
         E --- F (MASTER)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git branch old
git reset --hard retry
```

Will create (but not switch to) a new branch (called `old`) which points to the same commit as master and then move `master` to point to the same commit as `retry`.

Comment: Does this have any implications when pushing to public remotes?

Comment: Absolutely. You won't be able to push that without using `push -f` which will break anybody who has fetched since you committed C and D. If nobody has, you'll get away with it. You are effectively rewriting history by saying "I know you *think* master had C and D in it at some point, but it doesn't any more!"

Answer (score 1):

First, create some branch, say `old_master` to keep it as pointer to your failed work in `master`:

```
git branch old_master master
```

Now, make `master` point to F:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard F
```

Later, you can checkout to `old_master` to see your old bad commits.